# Check whether the first row is filled

Tags: c++

I have a matrix, and I want to check whether the first row is filled with "0" or "x"'s.
In my case that means that it's not "-"(empty).
The code below works only for each element of the board but I want it to check for the entire row at once.

```
bool checkBoardFull(string board[N][N], int n) {
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   if (board[0][i] != "-") {
     return false;
   }
 }
 return true;
}
```

Comment: Fyi, if this is supposed to return false upon encountering a `'-'` character, your condition logic is backward. `if (board[0][i] != "-")` tests whether the character is *not* a hyphen. Per your stated condition you want to return false when it *is* a hyphen (and therefore neither an `'x'` nor an `'O'`, or anything else for that matter). I.e. that should be `if (board[0][i] == "-")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the method to not return within the loop:

```
bool checkBoardFull(string board[N][N], int n) {
 bool full = true;
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   if (board[0][i] == "-") {
     full = false;
     break;
   }
 }
 return full;
}
```

Or, if you don't want that extra variable:

```
bool checkBoardFull(string board[N][N], int n) {
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   if (board[0][i] == "-") {
     return false;
   }
 }
 return true;
}
```

Comment: Yep! both work. Thank you...